# Calculate the product of multiple individual rows

Tags: jquery, html

Problem:
Any row added below the first always gives the product of the first row.

HTML mentioned below has a jQuery script that calculates the product of two values of input fields of a table row. Multiple rows that follow the first one also face the same issue.

Note : This is not my entire file but only the part where I face an issue.

```
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){


                $('.calc').on("keypress", function(e) {
                /* ENTER PRESSED*/
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        var ptag4 = 1;
                        var ptag1 = $(this).find('td.ryo input').val();
                        var ptag2 = $(this).find('td.qty input').val();
                        $(this).append(ptag4 + "," + ptag1 + "," + ptag2 + ", ");
                        var ptag3 = ptag1*ptag2;
                        //troubleshoot value fetch
                        $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').html(ptag3);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>




    <table class="calc">
        <tbody><tr class="ka">
            <th>Kōmoku-mei</th>
            <th>Kakaku</th>
            <th>Ryō</th>
            <th>Gōkei</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ka">
            <td class="kom">
                Gom Kōmoku
            </td>
            <td class="ryo">
                <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="val1" value="23">
            </td>
            <td class="qty">
                <input class="kin" type="text" name="val1" value="1">
            </td>
            <td class="gokei">
                276
            </td>
            <td class="closeb">
                X
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ka">
            <td class="kom">
                Gom Kōmoku
            </td>
            <td class="ryo">
                <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="val1" value="23">
            </td>
            <td class="qty">
                <input class="kin" type="text" name="val1" value="1">
            </td>
            <td class="gokei">
                276
            </td>
            <td class="closeb">
                X
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725232/6804958) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try this. Don't hardcode the way to access the elements. That makes life difficult sometimes. Just play with the `event` and you can do all what you want for this project.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


                $('.calc').on("keypress", function(e) {
                /* ENTER PRESSED*/
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      
                        var ptag4 = 1;
       
                        var ptag1 = $(e.target).parent().prev().find("input").val();
                        var ptag2 = $(e.target).val();
                        $(this).append(ptag4 + "," + ptag1 + "," + ptag2 + ", ");
                        var ptag3 = ptag1*ptag2;
                        //troubleshoot value fetch
                        $(e.target).parent().next().html(ptag3);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <table class="calc">
        <tbody><tr class="ka">
            <th>Kōmoku-mei</th>
            <th>Kakaku</th>
            <th>Ryō</th>
            <th>Gōkei</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ka">
            <td class="kom">
                Gom Kōmoku
            </td>
            <td class="ryo">
                <input readonly="readonly" class="shit" type="text" name="val1" value="23">
            </td>
            <td class="qty">
                <input class="kin" type="text" name="val1" value="1">
            </td>
            <td class="gokei">
                276
            </td>
            <td class="closeb">
                X
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ka">
            <td class="kom">
                Gom Kōmoku
            </td>
            <td class="ryo">
                <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="val1" value="23">
            </td>
            <td class="qty">
                <input class="kin" type="text" name="val1" value="1">
            </td>
            <td class="gokei">
                276
            </td>
            <td class="closeb">
                X
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ka">
            <td class="kom">
                Gom Kōmoku
            </td>
            <td class="ryo">
                <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="val1" value="23">
            </td>
            <td class="qty">
                <input class="kin" type="text" name="val1" value="1">
            </td>
            <td class="gokei">
                276
            </td>
            <td class="closeb">
                X
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about e.target.

Comment: Glad to know if that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your selector. It always gives you the first two input boxes. One of the many ways to solve it by using the `.closest()` selector. With closest you will get the closest textboxes.

Find more details about `.closesst` : https://api.jquery.com/closest/